# Excel If Condition matches in two column fetch value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, excel-2019

I am working on an excel simple query, where I am trying to fetch `Name` based on

1. first if the `ID` matches between two tables columns values
2. second if the `Status` column has a value of `Pick`, then Fetch the value from the `Name` column. Else `Do nothing` and `empty`

Here are my tables -

Table 2

```
ID.    Name
1001   Chris
1002   Leoe
1003   Nyle
```

Table 1

```
ID.    Status
1001   Pick
1002    No
1003   Pick
1004   Pick
```

Expected result

```
ID.    Status.  Name
1001   Pick     Chris
1002    No     
1003   Pick     Nyle
1004   Pick
```

I am trying this query but something is wrong here -

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([ID];Table2[ID];0));IF([Status]="Pick";Table2[Name];""))
```

But I am getting this error error

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use @ signs to reference the single row of the immediate table. You should also use the Match result again to reference the single row in the second table:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@ID]; Table2[ID]; 0)); IF([@Status]="Pick"; INDEX(Table2[Name]; MATCH([@ID]; Table2[ID]; 0)); ""); "")`

Comment: Note that if your users are all on the newest versions of O365, you can use a LET formula as well to store the value of the match. But that's just another potential optimization

Comment: @MacroMarc The advent of LET() had completely passed me by! Many thanks for alerting me.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your Table1 and Table2 are Excel tables, you can build the result table as a normal spreadsheet range in A11:C14 with the following formulas.

1. [A11] =Table2[ID.] This will automatically copy itself down to A14
2. [B11] =Table2[Status] This will automatically copy itself down to B14
3. [C11] `=IF(B11="Pick",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A11,Table1,2,FALSE),""),"")` Please copy down manually to C14.

The result will be as you describe but not as your sample illustrates because ID 1003 is associated with *Nyle*, not *Leoe*.

Comment: thank you for correcting my mistake and your awesome answer.